# How to Select a column in the inner join without group by SQL

Tags: sql

I have three tables users -> user_challenge <- challenge
and has many to many relationships

users table :

```
id | name | user_email
---+------+------
777 | "abc" | abc@abc.com
888 | "bcd" | bcd@bcd.com
```

user_challenge table

```
id | user_id | challenge_id
---+---------+-------------
1  |  777   |  22
2  |  777   |  23
3  |  888   |  23
```

challenge table

```
id | title | user_id
---+---------+-------------
21  |  "go"   |  777
22  |  "run"  |  888
23  |  "eat"  |  888
```

I want to group the number of users who is in the `challenge` table ( works fine here )

```
SELECT c.Id, c.title, COUNT(*) AS Count_joined
FROM Challenges AS c
   JOIN
   user_challenge AS ug
   ON c.id = ug.challenge_id
    JOIN
    users AS u
    ON ug.user_id = u.id

GROUP BY c.Id, c.title;
```

but when I want to take their email, so I added the `email` column in the `users` table like this :

```
SELECT c.Id, c.title, COUNT(*) AS Count_joined ,  u.email
FROM challenges AS c
   JOIN
   user_challenge AS ug
   ON c.id = ug.challenge_id
    JOIN
    users AS u
    ON ug.user_id = u.id

GROUP BY c.Id, c.title;
```

It shows error `[S0001][8120] Line 1: Column 'users.email' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

I need the result same as the following :

```
id | title | user_email
---+---------+-------------
21  |  "go"   |  abc@abc.com
22  |  "run"  |  bcd@bcd.com
23  |  "eat"  |  bcd@bcd.com
```

How I can select the email column for the same result I got from the first piece of the statement?

Comment: If you always expect 1 email to show up for a (c.Id, c.title) row, use MAX(u.email). Or add u.email to the GROUP BY - depending on what result you want.

Comment: What do you not understand about the error message?

Comment: please add sample input and expected output. Depending on what you imagine the output could be, the query may change.

Comment: I need to retrieve the email for users who are challenge table (the people who already shown their name from first query) as mentioned above 

@jarlh

Comment: why do you have a bridge table, it is unnecessary as you reference the user_id already, the table is not normlaized with user_id in chalange

Comment: it is because the creator of the challenge, and the bridge for who join to the challenge, anyway this is not my problem 

I need the email of users @nbk

Comment: then name the column properly this is confusing

Comment: and which database system are you using, as the usernames must concatinated and all databases have their own aggregation functions

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: Your example data doesn't match your expected results. According to your data, challenge 21 has no users mapped to it, and challenge 23 has two users mapped to it. But your expected data has one user each to challenges 21, 22 and 23. This also highlights the issue; if challenge 23 has two users, WHICH users' email do you want to return?

Comment: about the last point you mention the user's email of 888 since he is the create of challenge in challenge table 
@MatBailie

Comment: Then your query is faulty. You're currently trying to return the challenge taker's email address. You need an additional join on the user table to find the creator's email address (one join for the participants email addresses, and a second for the creator's email address)

Comment: I think you are got my view, can you please correct the query for me? 

@MatBailie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
  c.id,
  c.title,
  u.user_email,
  COUNT(uc.id) AS participant_count
FROM
  challenges        AS c
INNER JOIN
  users             AS u
    ON c.user_id = u.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  user_challenge    AS uc
    ON c.id = uc.challenge_id
GROUP BY
  c.id,
  c.title,
  u.user_email
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add email column in your group by clause

```
GROUP BY c.Id, c.title, u.email;
```

Comment: gives me different results from which I want